# I am using PHP Chrome HTML 2 PDF but unable to use Header and Footer in the PDF

Tags: php, pdf-to-html

Please find the below code:

```
<?php
use Spiritix\Html2Pdf\Converter;
use Spiritix\Html2Pdf\Input\StringInput;
use Spiritix\Html2Pdf\Output\DownloadOutput;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$html="<p>This is the Content</p>";
$input = new StringInput();
$input->setHtml($html);

$converter = new Converter($input, new DownloadOutput());

$converter->setOption('landscape', false);
$converter->setOption('displayHeaderFooter', true);
$converter->setOption('headerTemplate', '<p>Header Here</p>');
$converter->setOption('footerTemplate', '<p>Footer Here</p>');

$output = $converter->convert();
$output->download('SOL-'.date('Y-m-d-h-i-s').'.pdf');
?>
```

The above code is working fine except the Header and Footer part. Header and Footer is not showing in the PDF. Please provide some suggestion to solve this issue.

Followed the below link for reference:

https://github.com/spiritix/php-chrome-html2pdf

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and i found a solution here:
https://github.com/spiritix/php-chrome-html2pdf/issues/9

The main content overlays the header and footer so you have to set margins on your page in order to let your header ad footer to pop out....